# "Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset" and "not enough arguments for method map"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

The following code got the two errors on the last `map(...)`. What parameter is missing in the `map()` function? How to resolve the error of "encoder"?

**Error:**

```
Error:(60, 11) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
      .map(r => Cols(r.getInt(0), r.getString(1), r.getString(2), r.getString(3), r.getDouble(4), r.getDate(5), r.getString(6), r.getString(7), r.getDouble(8), r.getString(9)))

Error:(60, 11) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[Cols])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Cols].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
      .map(r => Cols(r.getInt(0), r.getString(1), r.getString(2), r.getString(3), r.getDouble(4), r.getDate(5), r.getString(6), r.getString(7), r.getDouble(8), r.getString(9)))
```

**Code:**

```
  case class Cols (A: Int,
                   B: String,
                   C: String,
                   D: String,
                   E: Double,
                   F: Date,
                   G: String,
                   H: String,
                   I: Double,
                   J: String
                  )

class SqlData(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, jdbcSqlConn: String) {
  def getAll(source: String) = {
    sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
      "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
      "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
      "dbtable" -> s"MyFunction('$source')"
    )).load()
      .select("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
      // The following line(60) got the errors.
      .map((r) => Cols(r.getInt(0), r.getString(1), r.getString(2), r.getString(3), r.getDouble(4), r.getDate(5), r.getString(6), r.getString(7), r.getDouble(8), r.getString(9)))
  }
}
```

---

**Update:**

I have the following function

```
def compare(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, dbo: Dataset[Cols], ods: Dataset[Cols]) = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._
    dbo.map((r) => ods.map((s) => { // Errors occur here
      0
    }))
```

and it got the same error.

1. Why it still has the error after I imported `sqlContext.implicits._`?
2. I create a new parameter `sqlContext` simply for importing. Is there a better way do it?

Comment: Why not `select.as[Cols]` ?

Comment: Did you `import spark.implicits._` as the error suggests? And, the missing argument is the implicit Encoder, so it's the same issue, solve one and you've solved the other.

Comment: @TzachZohar I got the error of `cannot resolve symbol implicits.` when I put `import org.apache.spark.implicits._` on the top?

Comment: @T.Gawęda `as[Cols]` got the same errors on `.as[Cols]`.

Comment: you should have an instance of SparkSession, it's usually named `spark`, and that's what you import. You can also use `import sqlContext.implicits._` using the `SQLContext` instance

Comment: Thanks. `import sqlContext.implicits._` made both `as[Cols]` and `.map()` work. I will need to understand the difference between the import from the instance and non-instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combining all the comments into an answer:

```
def getAll(source: String): Dataset[Cols] = {
  import sqlContext.implicits._ // this imports the necessary implicit Encoders

  sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(Map(
    "driver" -> "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver",
    "url" -> jdbcSqlConn,
    "dbtable" -> s"MyFunction('$source')"
  )).load().as[Cols] // shorter way to convert into Cols, thanks @T.Gaweda
}
```

Comment: I just updated the question at the bottom. A function still gets the error even after I imported the implicits?

Comment: I created a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150713/unable-to-find-encoder-for-type-stored-in-a-dataset-even-spark-implicits-is.