# "Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset" even spark.implicits._ is imported?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
Error:(39, 12) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    dbo.map((r) => ods.map((s) => {

Error:(39, 12) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int]])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Int]].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
    dbo.map((r) => ods.map((s) => {
```

```
object Main extends App {
  ....

  def compare(sqlContext: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext, 
            dbo: Dataset[Cols], ods: Dataset[Cols]) = {
    import sqlContext.implicits._ // Tried import dbo.sparkSession.implicits._ too
    dbo.map((r) => ods.map((s) => { // Errors occur here
      0
    }))
}

case class Cols (A: Int,
                   B: String,
                   C: String,
                   D: String,
                   E: Double,
                   F: Date,
                   G: String,
                   H: String,
                   I: Double,
                   J: String
                  )
```

1. Why it still has the error after I imported `sqlContext.implicits._`?
2. I created the parameter `sqlContext` only for importing. Is there a better way do it without passing a parameter?

   > This should be resolved by `import dbo.sparkSession.implicits._`

Comment: I tried `import dbo.sparkSession.implicits._` and it still gets the same error?

Comment: Looking at it again I think I see the problem, the error message says it should be `spark.implicits._` to import the encoders.  The other problem is you are trying to access another dataset within the map, this is not possible.  You will need to combine your datasets somehow(usually with a join)

Comment: Basically, I will need to get a value for each of all the combination of the two datasets and get the value greater than a threshold. So I will need to join the two datasets and then run the calculation on the joined datasets. Right? will the calculation be distributed to all the executors?

Comment: Yes, you need to join, then do your calculations on the resulting dataset.  Since you want all possible combinations that would be a cartesian.  Be aware that this will be very slow as many records will be generated (this is unavoidable if you truly want to match everything with everything, if you only need the data from one dataset to do the threshold filter, I would do the filter before joining).

Comment: Yes, I need to run the calculation on the cartesian result and return only the result satisfying some condition. That's why I'm converting the SQL server code to Spark so the calculation can be distributed to many executors (and execute in memory) to speed up the calculation.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is trying to create a Dataset[Dataset[Int]], that's wrong for several reasons

You can't use datasets inside a dataset, if you want to cross data from 2 datasets you need to join them somehow

There's no way a Encoder[Dataset[Int]] can be created, you could have Encoder[Int] but the other thing makes no sense

Something like this makes much more sense

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions => func

dbo.joinWith(ods, func.expr("true")).map {
  case (r, s) =>
    0
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually need to do cartesian join between two datasets. And I want to distribute the joinings to every executors. What's the best way to do it? Should I created an `array[DataSet[Cols]]` first?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make the cartesian product

Comment: Is `.joinWith(..., func.expr("true"))` same as `.crossJoin()`?

Comment: the joinWith is part of the Dataset api and the resutl is another Dataset[(Cols, Cols)] while the crossJoin will produce a Dataframe of rows that will contain all fields in each dataset, both things will produce same data in different format

Comment: Instead of `func.expr("true")` you can also use `func.lit(true)`.

Comment: @JackLeow I got the error of `Join condition is missing or trivial.
Use the CROSS JOIN syntax to allow cartesian products between these relations.;` when using `func.lit(true)`. Will try `func.expr("true")`, guess it will also get the same error.

Comment: @Mikel It has a strange issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153477/runtime-error-use-the-cross-join-syntax-to-allow-cartesian-products-between-the

Comment: @JackLeow A new question has been created. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45153477/runtime-error-use-the-cross-join-syntax-to-allow-cartesian-products-between-the