# Scala:not enough arguments for method map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
object test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val df = tdw.table("video",Seq("hello")).map(record=>{
      val kv = deal_json(record(3).toString)
      kv
    })
    df.first()
    sparkBuilder.stop()
  }
  def deal_json(data:String): JSONArray ={
    val jsonData=JSON.parseObject(data)
    val kv = jsonData.getJSONArray("feature")
    kv
  }
}
```

Getting this error:

> Error:(20, 71) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[com.alibaba.fastjson.JSONArray].
>       Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.
>           val df = tdw.table("video_t_boss_v1_6564",Seq("p_2018082309")).map(record=>{

Comment: It looks like it is looking for an implicit parameter which you are not importing anywhere. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45149861/8230810), maybe you need to import `import sqlContext.implicits._`?

Comment: if you can post the code for tdw then it would help use understand more